# How to retrieve data from a table from the same column but having different values in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

i have a table called (tickets) with (movie_id)column and (amount)column,
how can i retrieve a movie with the highest amount?thank you

```
 $movies = DB::table('tickets')->where('movie_id',$id)->having('amount', '>', 1000)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $movies = DB::table('tickets')->where('movie_id',$id)->orderBy('amount', 'desc')->get();
```

Or,

```
 $movie = DB::table('tickets')->where('movie_id',$id)->orderBy('amount', 'desc')->first();
```

to retrieve only one record.